# Custom CardDAV server: clients (especially iOS) don't seem to request actual contacts

Tags: asp.net-core, webdav, carddav

I'm trying to implement a custom CardDAV server on top of [NWebDAV](https://github.com/ramondeklein/nwebdav) and ASP.NET Core 3.1, using an existing database as the actual data source for contacts. (NWebDAV seems to have excellent support for basic WebDAV notions like responding to `PROPFIND`. Out of the box, running its sample project to serve your home directory seems to work great. OTOH, stuff like `REPORT` is apparently missing, and I'm not sure yet how much work that will be.)

I'm using iOS 13 as my main testing client.

I have successfully gotten it to:

- pass "validating" when adding my server as an account (including Basic auth)
- show multiple address books I'm serving in the Contacts app's Groups view

So I know it's parsing my `PROPFIND` responses to a point. But afterwards, nothing. From what I understand, it should issue some kind of `REPORT` request against my server, either to first do a complete sync, or — when typing something into the search field — to query particular contacts. It never seems to try.

I give it something like:

```xml
<addressbook-home-set xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav">
  <D:href>/addressbooks/sample/108</D:href>
  <D:href>/addressbooks/sample/109</D:href>
</addressbook-home-set>
```

And it issues a `PROPFIND` request against each of those address books, like so:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<A:propfind xmlns:A="DAV:">
  <A:prop>
    <A:add-member />
    <E:bulk-requests xmlns:E="http://me.com/_namespace/" />
    <A:current-user-privilege-set />
    <A:displayname />
    <E:guardian-restricted xmlns:E="http://me.com/_namespace/" />
    <D:max-image-size xmlns:D="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" />
    <D:max-resource-size xmlns:D="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" />
    <C:me-card xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/" />
    <A:owner />
    <C:push-transports xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/" />
    <C:pushkey xmlns:C="http://calendarserver.org/ns/" />
    <A:quota-available-bytes />
    <A:quota-used-bytes />
    <A:resource-id />
    <A:resourcetype />
    <A:supported-report-set />
    <A:sync-token />
  </A:prop>
</A:propfind>
```

I respond to this as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<D:multistatus xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:Z="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:">
  <D:response>
    <D:href>http://localhost:55946/addressbooks/sample/108</D:href>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:add-member />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}add-member is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <bulk-requests xmlns="http://me.com/_namespace/" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {http://me.com/_namespace/}bulk-requests is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <guardian-restricted xmlns="http://me.com/_namespace/" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {http://me.com/_namespace/}guardian-restricted is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <max-image-size xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav}max-image-size is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <max-resource-size xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav}max-resource-size is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:owner />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}owner is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <push-transports xmlns="http://calendarserver.org/ns/" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {http://calendarserver.org/ns/}push-transports is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <pushkey xmlns="http://calendarserver.org/ns/" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {http://calendarserver.org/ns/}pushkey is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:quota-available-bytes />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}quota-available-bytes is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:quota-used-bytes />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}quota-used-bytes is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:resource-id />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}resource-id is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:sync-token />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}sync-token is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:current-user-privilege-set>
          <D:privilege>
            <D:read />
          </D:privilege>
          <D:privilege>
            <D:read-acl />
          </D:privilege>
          <D:privilege>
            <D:read-current-user-privilege-set />
          </D:privilege>
          <D:privilege>
            <D:write />
          </D:privilege>
          <D:privilege>
            <D:bind />
          </D:privilege>
        </D:current-user-privilege-set>
        <D:displayname>SampleContacts108</D:displayname>
        <me-card xmlns="http://calendarserver.org/ns/">
          <D:href>/addressbooks/sample/108/contact-49191/</D:href>
        </me-card>
        <D:resourcetype>
          <D:collection />
          <addressbook xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" />
        </D:resourcetype>
        <D:supported-report-set>
          <D:supported-report>
            <addressbook-query xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" />
          </D:supported-report>
          <D:supported-report>
            <addressbook-multiget xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" />
          </D:supported-report>
          <D:supported-report>
            <D:expand-property />
          </D:supported-report>
        </D:supported-report-set>
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
    </D:propstat>
  </D:response>
  <D:response>
    <D:href>http://localhost:55946/addressbooks/sample/108/Bar,Foo</D:href>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:add-member />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}add-member is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <bulk-requests xmlns="http://me.com/_namespace/" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {http://me.com/_namespace/}bulk-requests is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:current-user-privilege-set />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}current-user-privilege-set is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <guardian-restricted xmlns="http://me.com/_namespace/" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {http://me.com/_namespace/}guardian-restricted is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <max-image-size xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav}max-image-size is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <max-resource-size xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:carddav}max-resource-size is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <me-card xmlns="http://calendarserver.org/ns/" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {http://calendarserver.org/ns/}me-card is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:owner />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}owner is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <push-transports xmlns="http://calendarserver.org/ns/" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {http://calendarserver.org/ns/}push-transports is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <pushkey xmlns="http://calendarserver.org/ns/" />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {http://calendarserver.org/ns/}pushkey is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:quota-available-bytes />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}quota-available-bytes is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:quota-used-bytes />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}quota-used-bytes is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:resource-id />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}resource-id is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:resourcetype />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}resourcetype is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:supported-report-set />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}supported-report-set is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:sync-token />
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</D:status>
      <D:responsedescription>Property {DAV:}sync-token is not supported.</D:responsedescription>
    </D:propstat>
    <D:propstat>
      <D:prop>
        <D:displayname>Bar, Foo</D:displayname>
      </D:prop>
      <D:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</D:status>
    </D:propstat>
  </D:response>
</D:multistatus>
```

(I've implemented `me-card` because someone said not doing so might crash iOS Contacts, and in hopes it would prompt iOS to *at least* try to fetch the me card. But alas.)

This response includes the metadata for both the address book itself, and a sample contact within. I'm not sure if that's correct, but leaving that contact out doesn't seem to change anything.

I'm supporting the reports `addessbook-query` and `addressbook-multiget`. My reading of [8. Address Book Reports](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6352#section-8) in the spec is that this should be enough to comply with the standard.

What puzzles me is that there's just… nothing. There's no user-facing error, there's no further request, etc.

I did find something in Console:

```
com.apple.dataaccess    debug   10:52:13.523530+0200    dataaccessd <private>: There are no server side items to grab, so I'm outta here
```

But I don't know if that refers to *this* account (could be a different server). If it does, I'd love to know what brings iOS to this conclusion?

So, my main question is: **do I have the basic assumption right that the CardDAV client should eventually issue a `REPORT` request to query contacts?**

Comment: Hm! Outlook CalDav Synchronizer _does_ issue `REPORT` when I explicitly ask it to sync. So it's _probably_ some special protocol iOS wants?

Comment: Yup, I can return a simple report containing vCards, and those show up in Outlook. So what does iOS expect differently? Is `sync-token` support mandatory in iOS?